# Total Energy of an Asymetric 3x3 Coupler

Tags: energy-conservation, interference, interferometry, fiber-optics, waveguide

In our experiments, we are using a [3×3 fibre couplers](https://community.fs.com/blog/how-do-different-fiber-optic-couplers-work.html) with light as part of an interferometer-setup. This coupler isn't symmetric; it's phase relation of every output is unequal to 120° and the amplitude (and offset) of the intensity of every output is different from each other.

For a complete symmetric coupler, the sum of the intensity of every output would result in a constant value. However, I noticed that for an asymmetric coupler the sum becomes a cosine function of the form
$$I_{\text{tot}} = A\cos(\varphi-\alpha)+B$$
with constants $A, \alpha$, the interferometric phase $\varphi$ and the sum intensity of every Output $I_{\text{tot}}$. I could confirm this with some experiments. Since $I_{\text{tot}}$ is not constant, there seem to be energy lost, because for some $\varphi$ the sum of intensities is lower than others.

Where is this energy gone? What is really the total energy of all outputs? Since some energy is missing, the only conclusion would be that $I_{\text{tot}}$ describes only for a symmetric 3×3 coupler the total intensity and term is missing (because the energy must converse).

Comment: please describe what a $3\times 3$ coupler is, or do you mean a 3-port coupler?

Comment: I mean fibre based couplers. I added a link in my post now, with a brief description of them.

Comment: if this were an RF/microwave coupler I would say it is reflected. Have you measured the return loss of the coupler with matched/mismatched loads?

Comment: Thanks, I will check this out!